# How to print first two fields in a file?

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep, cut

I have a file with country names and then the mobile country code prefix for that country like this:

```
United Kingdom   +44  ...more fields
United States Virgin Islands +1  ...more fields
```

I need to get the country name and the mobile prefix. So the regular expression reads like: read all words from the beginning of the line and then a string that starts with a plus and one more more digits and then stop.

I tried a few things with grep, cut, and even sed but I can't get it.

Comment: What character delimits the fields/words of the data? Space or tab?

Comment: It's a space delimited file

Comment: If you can use `perl` you could use something like this: `cat /tmp/b.log | perl -ne '/(United.*)(\+[0-9]{1,2})/ && print ("1:" . $1 . "2: ". $2 . "\n")'`. This assumes that `/tmp/b.log` is your file. This prints:
`1:United Kingdom   2: +44 <CR>
1:United States Virgin Islands 2: +1`

Comment: @mnille perl is too brutal for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try with:

```
grep -o '^[^+]*+[0-9]\+' infile
```

`[^+]*+` matches everything until first `+` found followed by one-or-more digits `[0-9]\+`

Comment: This will return the whole line but I want to do is extract the country and the mobile prefix. That's why I tried to use cut

Comment: @C.S Using GNU `grep`, the given command does exactly what you seem to want to do on my machine.  What Unix are you using?

Comment: No, it works. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

**Command line:**

```
$ perl -lne 'print /^(.*?\+\d+)/' input.txt
```

This will get you the desired info from the input.

**Working:**

- `/^(.*?\+\d+)/` regex shall extract everything upto the first occurrence of a plus  symbol followed by atleast one digit symbol.
- Since this is hooked to the `BOL` via the `^` caret symbol, so obviously only one matching can happen.
- The matching is passed on to the `print` function.
- `-lne` options are to run `Perl` code given in the `-e` option on each line of the input.file. `-n` makes perl not to print anything unless specifically asked to.

**Output:**

```
United Kingdom   +44
United States Virgin Islands +1
```

Answer (score 1):

Since [you say](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/521699/how-to-print-first-two-fields-in-a-file#comment964294_521699) *space* is the delimiter used in your file, you should be able to use

```
cut -d ' ' -f 1-5 filename
```

to extract the five first columns from the file.

For the given data, this produces

```
United Kingdom   +44
United States Virgin Islands +1
```

... but I'm assuming that this is only by luck, as a country with more than two words in its name would span multiple fields (not just two).

A more robust method using `sed` to delete everything after the first set of digits on each line (i.e., everything after the country code):

```
sed 's/\([[:digit:]][[:digit:]]*\).*/\1/' filename
```

or,

```
sed 's/\([[:digit:]]\{1,\}\).*/\1/' filename
```

or, with `-E` and an extended regular expression instead,

```
sed -E 's/([[:digit:]]+).*/\1/' filename
```

Comment: Or `sed 's/\([[:digit:]]\{1,\}\).*/\1/'`, `\{1,\}` being the standard BRE equivalent of ERE `+`.